# How can I check in Python is my Flask app is already running in background

Tags: python, linux, flask, subprocess, python-os

I am just trying to figure out before running my Flask app I need to check is the Flask app is running already running (in the background).

I tried using subprocess library but that doesn't seem to work.

```
processes = subprocess.Popen('tasklist', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why you want to know it?

If you want to restart your app when it crashed, or your server rebooted, you can do that with `systemd` or with `supervisor`.

If you really want to know whether there is a process running, there are many ways...

For example you can get the current processes like this...

```
os.system("ps aux")
```

Then, it certainly depends on how you started your application.

I start `Flask` with `python wsgi.py`, so I look for that line and the I find...

```
jugmac00 12786  3.1  0.1  78680 28068 pts/1    S+   16:46   0:00 python wsgi.py
```

Comment: using os.system("ps aux") we come to know the list of processes running but I need to confirm where for example python wsgi.py is present in '''ps aux'''

Comment: What do you mean with "where is present"? You always can do a simple check like `"a" in "apple"`